# Setting Parameter fields dynamically for a SqlDataSource

Tags: asp.net

I need to fill in the "SelectParameters" dynamically , but all I found on Google , was using fixed parameters.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="XX"
                            OnSelecting="SqlDataSource2_Selecting" SelectCommand="">
                            <SelectParameters>
                            </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Is there any solutions ?

I also tried to use the "OnSelecting" event , but I can't assign value to parameters that are not present.

```
 protected void SqlDataSource2_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] queryFields = new string[] { ... }; // some dynamic field depends on different table

        foreach (string s in queryFields)
        {
            e.Command.Parameters["@" + s].Value = "filter";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you want to set the values of the parameters dynamic or the variables and value?

Comment: @Arion only the parameter fields , I know how to set values but failed when the parameter was not present (I just updated my question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can in code behind set the variables like this:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("parameterName", "parameterValue");
```

But be aware that you need the clear the parameters before adding them. Because otherwise you will end up with duplicates of parameters.

Answer (score -1):

If you're ok with setting the connection string when initializing the control you can do so on the control's init event like this:

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = <whatever code you want here>;
     SqlDataSource1.ProviderName = <whatever code you want here>;
}
```

This is still dynamic in the sense that you determine the connection properties at runtime, not design time.  This helped me avoid having to resort to web.xml transformations and switch between QA and PROD connection strings based on an environment variable specifying QA/PROD environment.